# How to modify a specific derivation option in nix package manager

Tags: nix, nixos, darwin

I want to modify the definition of a Nix derivation ([emacs macport](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/nixos-unstable/pkgs/applications/editors/emacs/macport.nix#L65)). I wish to change the `configureFlag` value and "--with-mac-metal" to it.

I have tried the following with no luck:

```hs
  emacsMacport.overrideDerivation
  (old: {
    configureFlags = [
      "LDFLAGS=-L${ncurses.out}/lib"
      "--with-xml2=yes"
      "--with-gnutls=yes"
      "--with-mac"
      "--with-modules"
      "--enable-mac-app=$$out/Applications"
      "--with-mac-metal"
    ];
  })
```

I am using home-manager and nix-darwin, and I get the following exception:

```sh
error: A definition for option `home-manager.users.ashk.home.packages.[definition 16-entry 3]' is not of type `package'. Definition values:
       - In `/nix/store/mkcwa9i9brbxf81a01whhy53yzk87c9d-source/modules/hosts/zebra/home.nix': <function>
(use '--show-trace' to show detailed location information)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to parenthesize function applications when they're in a list literal.
It's weird.

You'll probably never get used to this, judging from my own experience using Nix extensively for years.